# convert string to html (hyperlink)

Tags: c#

i defined ToHtml() extension for string class and convert break to `<br/>`.
how can detect hyper link and convert to `<a>` element?

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string ToHtml(this string item)
    {
        //\r\n windows
        //\n unix
        //\r mac os
        return item.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>").Replace("\n", "<br/>").Replace("\r", "<br/>");
    }
}
```

c#, asp.net

Comment: Define a `hyperlink` in this context. Text does not have links, so having a good definition is important.

Comment: For your current implementation you may want to consider using Environment.NewLine. Also, what do you expect an hyperlink to look like in your string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[see this one](http://rickyrosario.com/blog/converting-a-url-into-a-link-in-csharp-using-regular-expressions/), uses regex

```
private string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string msg) {
    string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
    Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"Click to open in a new window or tab\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression here to identify where the hyperlink begins and ends (possibly based on the length of the match)
Then add in your anchor tags before and after.

Answer (score 1):

By using:

```
string strContent = YourText;
Regex urlregex = new Regex(@"(http:\/\/([\w.]+\/?)\S*)",
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase| RegexOptions.Compiled);
strContent = urlregex.Replace(strContent, 
             "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
```